# jquery crSpline : weird animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

I tried the jquery crSpline plugin (http://ijin.net/crSpline/demo.html), but I have some weird movement with the last but one coordinate.

The top property of the red point goes wild with the last but one position (something like -3000px).

Here you can find some code: https://github.com/xseignard/test-crspline

and the demo here: http://xseignard.github.com/test-crspline/

Do you see something wrong?

Or even better, since the plugin development seems to be dead, do you have an alternative?

Regards,

Xavier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is so, that you do not convert string values of `x` and `y` to integers. That's why the maths works with strings and do string concatenation instead of sum (e.g. in `generateExtension` method).

Just add `parseInt` to your coordinates conversion and everything will work.

```
$.each(json, function() {
    points.push([parseInt(this.x, 10), parseInt(this.y, 10)]);
});
```